# zoom in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'd like to zoom to a point with google map but I want to use the android sdk 8 and not 11

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

and

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mc = mapView.getController();
```

But I have the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.maps.MapView
```

So I'd like to zoom to a point wiht the sdk8

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call getMap(), not findViewById. The pattern is documented in
[Map Objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#verify_map_availability) in the Maps API v2 for Android guide.

Comment: yes but I can't use getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map) this is sdk 11

Comment: I finaly find using getSupportFragmentManager(), not getFragmentManager()

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
GoogleMap map = getMap();
```

Note that the class GoogleMap is from "com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap" package.